# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'smbclient.so'

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I updated Ubunto 18 to Ubuntu 20

now when I run a composer I get `Warning` messages

```
$ composer

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'smbclient.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so: undefined symbol: smbc_setOptionProtocols, version SMBCLIENT_0.2.3), /usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'smbclient.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so: undefined symbol: smbc_setOptionProtocols, version SMBCLIENT_0.2.3), /usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/smbclient.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Please help me understand it and fix it

Comment: Might need to install the samba-client.

Comment: Yes, I tried `sudo apt install smbclient` it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I looked for what I have

```
$ apt list --installed | grep -i smb

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libsmbclient/focal-updates,now 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 amd64 [installed]
libsmbios-c2/focal,now 2.4.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.0-smbclient/now 1.0.6-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+10 amd64 [installed,local]
smbclient/focal-updates,now 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 amd64 [installed]
```

and removed some

```
$ sudo apt-get remove smbclient/focal-updates
$ sudo apt-get remove php8.0-smbclient
$ sudo apt-get remove libsmbclient/focal-updates
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

so I only left with this

```
libsmbios-c2/focal,now 2.4.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

The warnings have gone now